# How to call a custom function from html with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'd like to define separate methods within my `js` controllers as follows:

```
    angular.module('test').controller('mycontroller', mycontroller);
    function mycontroller() {
        //do sth
    };

    function test(value) {
        console.log(value); //this is never written
    };
```

This way I'd have a clean structure and each method separated in its own block.

But when I try to use it as follows, there is not output.

```
<div ng-controller='mycontroller'>
    {{test('printme')}}
</div>
```

Why?

Comment: When you set mycontroller as the controller to use, the scope gets bound to the components. `test` doesn't exist on this scope. Therefore you're better off putting `function test(value) {}` onto a scope variable, say `$scope.test`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/tYYvssVWUfvHyXE8ilD8?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep you files looking clean you can follow John Papa's style guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Here is how I fixed your question and applied a clean approach to it: http://plnkr.co/edit/tYYvssVWUfvHyXE8ilD8?p=preview

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ctrl);

function ctrl($scope) {
  /* -- Public Properties & Methods -- */

  $scope.test = test;


  /* -- Private Properties & Methods -- */

  function test(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

Because my code is in an IIFE, you can actually have that `function test` anywhere inside of that block, instead of having it inside the controller function:

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ctrl);

function ctrl($scope) {
  /* -- Public Properties & Methods -- */

  $scope.test = test; 
}

/* -- Private Properties & Methods -- */
function test(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VXbOuOvHaIhRFBVZD16p?p=preview

I just had a thought about doing this according to the second way. A fair amount of times we create variables we wish to bind to the DOM: `$scope.showOptions`. If we have the function outside of the controller we no longer have access to this `$scope.showOptions` so you would have "difficulty" interrogating it. You could easily get around this by either requesting the variables/scope through the function parameter. Or creating a small wrapper function that will dispatch out (almost like double dispatching).

```
$scope.test = function test() { testImpl($scope.showOptions); };

function testImpl(showOptions) {
    console.log(showOptions);
}
```

This will allow you to keep all of your main heavy lifting outside the controller but does introduce a new layer of complexity, one which I know I could certainly do without.

So the choice is yours.

Comment: That was probably what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting your test function inside your controller, and change it to

```
$scope.test = function(value){
    console.log(value)
};
```

Also add $scope dependency to your controller

Comment: That works. But is there also a way to define the function block outside of the controller function, and just settings the reference to that function to the scope?